# send a list of all leads whose status is changed to 2InProgess to their respective owners at the end of the day

Tags: email, list, leads

Suppose there is a picklist field called status on Lead object with picklist values as

1. New
2. InProgress
3. Closed.

How to send a list of all leads whose status is changed to 2. InProgess to their respective owners at the end of the day.

Comment: can anyone help me please on this

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create a report which will have the leads with In Progress status and schedule the report to run everyday
2) Create a batch class which will pick the leads whose status is changed today to In Progress. Create a CSV of these leads and send the email to the respective owners. Schedule the batch class to run everyday

Comment: Thank you Shailesh Patil for the help. We need to send the only those list of leads to the owner which belong to him only not all the lead, so i doubt if the 1st solution will work. I think the 2nd method should work but i don't know how will i take only those records whose status is changed today only and how to create csv to send to  each owner. Can you please write some rough code so that it will help me to understand it better.